# Differerent outputs in VSCode vs Prutor

Tags: c, operators, variable-assignment

I tried using the following C code:

```
int a=1,b=3;
printf("a : %d \n b : %d\ncond : %d\na : %d\nb : %d",a, b, ((a=b++)==0),a,b);
return 0;
```

I get different outputs in VSCode and Prutor(which is used in my college)

VSCode Output:

a : 3
b : 4 
cond : 0
a : 3
b : 4

Prutor Output:

a : 1
b : 3 
cond : 0
a : 3
b : 4

---

PS I feel that Prutor output is correct

Comment: Two words: sequence point

Comment: Lack thereof I mean.

Comment: Why can't *both* be correct?

Comment: In addition to the lack of sequence point, the order of evaluation of the parameters is not specified.

Comment: @ScottHunter Or both be incorrect? Or neither, as "correct" and  "incorrect" is undefined here

Comment: I don't know Prutor, but VSCode is no compiler at all. Comparing the result is not very useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior)